# Consequences of SecurityPermission and SecurityPermissionFlag.SkipVerification

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-4.5, code-access-security

In the MSDN documentation, [SecurityPermissionFlag.SkipVerification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionflag.aspx) says:

> Ability to skip verification of code in this assembly. Code that is
>   unverifiable can be run if this permission is granted.
>
> This is a powerful permission that should be granted only to highly
>   trusted code.
>
> This flag has no effect when used dynamically with stack modifiers
>   such as Deny, Assert, and PermitOnly.

Some project that I'm currently developing demanded me the `SkipVerificationFlag`. The concrete case is some custom class creating an instance of an inversion of control component using *Castle Windsor* **because the assembly calling the whole method isn't fully-trusted**.

This could be the pseudo-code in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) for the method with `SkipVerification`:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[ReflectionPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, SkipVerification = true)]
public override TComponent Resolve<TComponent>(string id = null, bool release = true, object argumentsAsAnonymousObject = null)
{
     // Some stuff...
     windsorContainer.Resolve<TComponent>(...);
}
```

The *Castle Windsor* assembly is fully-trusted in the `AppDomain`.

### So the question is...

**Am I wrong if I believe that I'm just trusting the Castle Windsor code and no more?**

*The consumer/caller of the above pseudo-code is in an untrusted (not fully-trusted) `AppDomain`. Or in other words: the third-party code using that door is security transparent.*

*From my point of view, as Castle Windsor doesn't do dangerous things, it's safe to use the whole flag for it*.

**What are the *bad* consequences of my decision in terms of security?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, and with the available info, it seems that there's no other consequence on asserting `SkipValidation`.

If you can fully rely on the code being executed inside the critical section, it can be considered *safe code*, thus no problem with Castle Windsor (or any other trusted code).